# Number of population in an existing buffer in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, spatial-query

I have a spatial table named Operation with points with 100m buffer for all the points, I also have another table with polygon shapefiles, which contains population

> ew is the population in each polygon [image: Population table]

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1cddb802069a493b06292e6ec0f55625)

Is it possible to add the population as a column into the Operation table by counting the population inside each buffer? As I am new to PostgreSQL I can't get any idea how to proceed with this.

```
ALTER TABLE public."Operation" ADD COLUMN population int;

UPDATE public."Operation" o 
SET population = (SELECT pop_per_sq count(*) FROM public."Restaurants" s
           WHERE ST_Contains(o.buffer,s.geom));
```

The result should be like a new column in the operation table with the population count.

Comment: you will need a trigger, to keep that value updated

Comment: @Aravinth can you provide some data samples (preferably in a fiddle) and the expected results?

Comment: @Aravinth you have to create the tables and the insert statements in the fiddle, so that your environment can be reproduced

Comment: @Aravinth try to work further here (most likely pg13 at dbfiffdle.uk has no postgis): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4eab004f4ba5328a33319141cfe29173

Comment: @Aravinth I don't see how it relates to the current question. Create insert statements for the lon,lat values and create the buffer from them. I believe I addressed it in another question of yours.

Comment: @Aravinth you don't have to use the `osm` data, just create a dummy geometry :) the whole idea is to reproduce your environment, but it can be with any data... as long as they represent your use case.

Comment: @JimJones, the fiddle table is added for the question kindly have a look, [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1cddb802069a493b06292e6ec0f55625)

Comment: @Aravinth is this what you want to achieve? `UPDATE public."Operation" o 
SET population = (SELECT count(ew) FROM public."Population" s
                  WHERE ST_Contains(o.buffer,s.geom));`

Comment: @JimJones, this gives only the number of polygon inside the buffer but I want to achieve the population count inside the buffer. Is it possible?

Comment: @Aravinth oh, I see: maybe this: `UPDATE public."Operation" o 
SET population = (SELECT sum(ew) FROM public."Population" s
                  WHERE ST_Contains(o.buffer,s.geom));`

Comment: @JimJones, Yes this works. But what happens if multiple polygons are inside a single buffer. In the fiddle, it shows null in that case.

Comment: @Aravinth I just added an answer containing `colaesce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close. The correct syntax for the aggregate function `count()` is `count(column)` not `column count(*)`. But what you need is rather `sum()`, which follows the same syntax. In case there is no overlap between buffer and polygons the result will be `null`. Also, if you do not wish to have `null` values in your table, use  `coalesce` to replace them values with `0`. This should fix your query:

```
UPDATE public."Operation" o 
SET population = coalesce((SELECT sum(ew) FROM public."Population" s
                           WHERE ST_Contains(o.buffer,s.geom)),0);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=37fc301773ff0ae2e84f5e202ff1839f)

**Note**: If you also want to count the polygons that partially overlap with the buffer, take a look at `ST_Intersects`. And keep in mind that if two (or more) buffers overlap and if their corresponding population geometries are inside both buffers, they will be calculated twice.

btw +1 for the nice fiddle, it is much easier to understand a question like this!

Comment: if it calculates a single buffer it's fine, but within that single buffer let's say 4 population geometries will it add all the result?

Comment: @Aravinth if the 4 population geometries have a `ew` grater than `0` it will be added to the final result :)